# Availability Test on Azure Application Insight fails on all location

Tags: azure, azure-web-apps, application-insights

I have set up an Availability test on one of our web apps. The test on five locations that were setup all fails but when I visit the site it is up and running. This is not a timing issue as the failed test keeps on coming, and I visit the site once I see a failed test reported on Azure (I also get email notification). If I click on a failed location and click on the "Failed" *results item* there is not much info there.

The response body is this

> There is no response body in this step.

Exception is

> System.Exception: Failure
>
> **** NOTE: This is not a real web request ****
>
> 1 primary requests, 0 dependant requests and 0 conditional rules
>   failed

The app service was running perfectly before this incident occured today. What am I missing?

Comment: Could you resolve your issue? I'm encountering a similar issue.

Comment: Sorry, I have not  :(

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned in the comments I encountered the same problem.
4 out of 7 locations failed (sometimes), navigating to the endpoint in the browser always worked.

I've figured out that always locations which failed, were far away from my location. So I presumed that it may have something to do with network (lag).

I'm running a Kestrel server on a Azure cloud service and I figured out there is something called [MinRequestBodyDataRate](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x#kestrel-options):

> Kestrel checks every second if data is arriving at the specified rate in bytes/second. If the rate drops below the minimum, the connection is timed out

The default value of this property is 240 bytes/second with a 5 second grace period. So I just lowered this rate to 100 bytes/second with a 10 seconds grace period. Since this change I had no more failing test locations.

Unfortunately I'm not familiar with Azure web apps, so I can't tell if you can even change those settings. Maybe this info guides you to the right solution or helps somebody coming from a google search.